# How to display JSON in a UILabel

Tags: json, swift3, uilabel, xcode8, ios10

I am trying to display retrieved JSON data as a UILabel. Currently I have the data successfully displaying in the debugger but I am unsure how to set the data equivalent to a UILabel. Any help would be appreciated.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var tableview: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let url = URL(string: "http://cgi.soic.indiana.edu/~team10/index.php")

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in
        if error != nil
        {
            print ("ERROR")
        }
        else
        {
            if let content = data
            {
                do
                {
                    //Array
                    let myJson = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: content, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as AnyObject
                        print(myJson)

                }
                catch
                {

                }
            }
        }
    }
    task.resume()

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the code below (`data` is a parameter from callback method in `URLSession dataTask`):

```
let body = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as AnyObject
var jsonString = String()
do {
    let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: body, options: .prettyPrinted)
    jsonString = String(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8)!
    print("jsonString: \(jsonString)")
} catch let error as NSError {
    print(error)
}          
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.sampleLabel.text = jsonString
}
```